# assigning pixels as 0 and 1

Tags: python, if-statement, boolean, pixel

remote sensing python:

is there a way to create a new band or array with DN values of only 0 and 1, based on conditional statements derived from DN values of two separate bands? for example, if values in band 4 => 11000 and values in band 11 <= 23000, set as 0, else set as 1.

Comment: If you give a more specific input example I can update my answer to be less general.

Comment: Essentially, I am using a red and thermal band from the a satellite image, each with different ranges of DN values, and am trying to identify cloud pixels (which have DN's that fall within the threshold I gave). I want to assign the cloud pixels as 0 and the rest as 1, so that I can create a mask and then multiply it by the rest of the bands to create an output with clouds pixels = 0 and the rest of the pixels remaining the same.. Not sure if that is clear, I am new to coding!

Comment: Can you just show some sample input?

Answer (score 1):

You could just use Python's ternary operator and a list comprehension:

```
>>> vals = [10000, 500, 200, 10290, 10290129, 3]
>>> vals = [1 if i > 500 else 0 for i in vals]
>>> vals
[1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
```

Or using numpy (always a good option):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> vals = np.array([10000, 500, 200, 10290, 10290129, 3])
>>> vals = (vals > 500).astype(int)
>>> vals
array([1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0])
```

Some timings:

```
In [4]: vals = np.random.rand(10000)

In [6]: %timeit [1 if i >= 0.5 else 0 for i in vals]
1.26 ms ± 105 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [7]: %timeit [int(i >= 0.5) for i in vals]
5.18 ms ± 61 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [8]: %timeit (vals >= 0.5).astype(int)
12.9 µs ± 308 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

As usual, numpy wins, followed by ternary, and then int conversion.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `int()` to convert a boolean to a `0` or `1`:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> [int(2 < i < 5) for i in l]
[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```